# Determine if individuals in a dataframe met a certain condition in a given time period in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, case-when

I have data which looks like this

```
pop_df <- data.frame(
  uniq_ID = c("AFG1234", "WED1234", "POJ1234", "DER234", "QWE1234", "BGR1234", "ABC1234", "DSE1234", "UHJ1234", "POI234",
              "EDC1234", "BGT1234", "MJI1234", "WEX1234", "FGH1234", "UJN1234", "LOK1234", "DRT1234", "URD1234", "MVR1234",
              "AFG1234", "WED1234", "POJ1234", "DER234", "QWE1234", "BGR1234", "ABC1234", "DSE1234", "UHJ1234", "POI234",
              "EDC1234", "BGT1234", "MJI1234", "WEX1234", "FGH1234", "UJN1234", "LOK1234", "DRT1234", "URD1234", "MVR1234",
              "AFG1234", "WED1234", "POJ1234", "DER234", "QWE1234", "BGR1234", "ABC1234", "DSE1234", "UHJ1234", "POI234",
              "EDC1234", "BGT1234", "MJI1234", "WEX1234", "FGH1234", "UJN1234", "LOK1234", "DRT1234", "URD1234", "MVR1234",
              "AFG1234", "WED1234", "POJ1234", "DER234", "QWE1234", "BGR1234", "ABC1234", "DSE1234", "UHJ1234", "POI234",
              "EDC1234", "BGT1234", "MJI1234", "WEX1234", "FGH1234", "UJN1234", "LOK1234", "DRT1234", "URD1234", "MVR1234"),
  Quarter = c((rep("20170101",20)), (rep("20170401",20)), (rep("20170701",20)), (rep("20171001",20))),
  contact = sample(c(0,1), replace = T, size = 80),
  )
```

This is a list of unique IDs, the quarter (ie three month period in the year), and whether or not they made contact with a doctor in that quarter. 
What I want to know is if someone made contact in the entire year of 2017, based on the value of "contact". 
So, for each unique ID, if contact == 1 in any quarter, then they made contact in 2017.

My desired output is a new variable, called contact_year, where the value is 1 for each unique ID if that unique ID made contact in any quarter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to group by 'uniq_ID' and check if there are `any` 'contact'

```
library(dplyr)
pop_df %>%
   group_by(uniq_ID) %>% 
   mutate(contact_year = as.integer(any(as.logical(contact))))
```

In the OP's example there was only 2017 data.  If it also includes other dates, we can create a logical index with `&`

```
pop_df %>%
    group_by(uniq_ID) %>% 
    mutate(contact_year = as.integer(any(as.logical(contact) & 
                               substr(Quarter, 1, 4) == 2017)))
```

Comment: Hi @Akrun, I have been using this answer successfully for some time now. Thanks.  However, I am now looking at creating this data for a 15 year time period. This is very slow to run (like, hours), and I wondered if you know if there's a way I can reduce the time taken? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Laura You can try `library(data.table);setDT(pop_df)[, contact_year := as.integer(any(as.logical(contact))), uniq_ID]`

Answer (score 1):

We could `sum` the `contact` info and find out the `uniq_ID` which has value greater than 0.

```
library(dplyr)

pop_df %>%
  group_by(uniq_ID) %>%
  mutate(contact_year = as.integer(sum(contact) > 0))
```

which in base R would be using `ave`

```
pop_df$contact_year <- as.integer(with(pop_df, ave(contact, uniq_ID,FUN = sum) > 0))
```

If we have more years and would like to do it for each ID in each year, we can extract the year information

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

pop_df %>%
  group_by(uniq_ID, year = year(ymd(Quarter))) %>%
  mutate(contact_year = as.integer(sum(contact) > 0))
```

This gives you same number of rows as your original `pop_df` with `contact_year` information repeated for each `uniq_ID`. You might also consider using `summarise` in `dplyr` and `aggregate` in base R which would give you only one row per `ID`.